# how to pass data from virtual assistant to a skill and vice versa

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to pass data from VA to a Skill like below in RouteStepAsync event in MainDialog of VA:

```cs
var dispatchIntentSkill = dispatchIntent.ToString();
var skillDialogArgs = new SkillDialogArgs { SkillId = dispatchIntentSkill, Text = userProfile.CorpId };
// Start the skill dialog.
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(dispatchIntentSkill, skillDialogArgs);
```

How do I read the data that is passed to Skill in Skill project?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/2456#issuecomment-602568038) GitHub comment which clearly explains the detailed steps.